# How fix error in install and connect apache cassandra on win?

Tags: cassandra

When I use the command `bin/cassandra install` in git bash it displays this error:

```
$ Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon
```

It completes on "cmd," but when I use `bin/cqlsh` I get this error:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', 
{'127.0.0.1': error(10061, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)].
Last error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it")})
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Please edit the question and put this information in the comment above as part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

for install cassandra on windows , only way for this work , should we install it with datastax? or can we install cassandra only?